# How to query whole word in Java MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, conditional-operator

I'm using Java Mongo DB driver.
Im doing some OR and AND operation to query the collection.

```
QueryObj = new BasicDBObject("key1",Pattern.compile("v",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
QueryList.add(QueryObj);
DBObject OrQuery = new BasicDBObject("$or", QueryList);
DBCursor cursor = MyCollection.find(OrQuery);
```

my Sample collection have 4 rows(JSON format might be wrong)

```
{
"key1": ["val1","val3"]
},
{
"key1": ["val2","val3"]
},
{
"key1": ["val3"]
},
{
"key1": ["val1","val2"]
}
```

If i search for "val2"

```
QueryObj = new BasicDBObject("key1",Pattern.compile("val2",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
```

i'm getting expected output 2nd and 4th row

```
{
"key1": ["val2","val3"]
},
{
"key1": ["val1","val2"]
}
```

if i search just "v"

```
QueryObj = new BasicDBObject("key1",Pattern.compile("v",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));
```

i should get null set, but getting all the 4 rows, though the array have a character "v".
i need to search the whole word.

Comment: so what happens when you use `val1` as keyword?

Comment: h4bo - if i use "val1" im getting expected rows, but if i give just "v" for that also i'm getting all the rows contains the char "v".

Comment: you must rephrase your question - I can't see the problem here. can you provide an example of collection, search query, expected results and actual results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to search for the complete word 'v' -- in which case, I believe your pattern would be as follows where ^ denote the start of word and $ denote the end of word.

QueryObj = new BasicDBObject("key1",Pattern.compile("^v$",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE));

Regards,

Kay

Answer (score 0):

I hope it should help you

```
 values ="val1";
```

CMD we use in DB as :

```
 db.collection_name.findOne({ key1: "val1"})
```

Likewise use

```
query.put("key1", values)
```

Use the `findOne()` instead of `find()` in the statement

Correct me if 'm wrong

Comment: Sorry stranger, i need to get multiple rows but need to search the whole word....

Answer (score 0):

If you have the 4 documents above you can just use the following query to retrieve only the ones you need:

```
 db.collection.find({"key1": "val2"})
```

This returns:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("507587fdf1ab6b3d9e0151d3"), "key1" : [ "val2", "val3" ] }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("50758801f1ab6b3d9e0151d5"), "key1" : [ "val1", "val2" ] }
```

(assuming your collection is called 'collection').

In the Java Driver the correct call should be:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
DB db = mongo.getDB("test");
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("key1", "val2");
db.getCollection("collection").find(query);
//omitting try catch
```

If I understand your question correct, you don't need to use a Pattern here.
hope this helps